# Why can't I change my MAC address?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

Here's what I got:

```
audrianore@HP-Mini-210-1000:~$ sudo airmon-ng stop eth1
[sudo] password for audrianore: 


Interface   Chipset     Driver

eth1        Unknown         wl (monitor mode disabled)

audrianore@HP-Mini-210-1000:~$ sudo ifconfig eth1 down
audrianore@HP-Mini-210-1000:~$ sudo macchanger --random eth1
Permanent MAC: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Xerox Corporation)
Current   MAC: ee:68:56:21:3b:2a (unknown)
ERROR: Can't change MAC: interface up or not permission: Too many open files in system
audrianore@HP-Mini-210-1000:~$
```

I don't know why, the Chipset is Unknown, but that doesn't matter (I think).
I was just curious with `macchanger`'s error.

What I did today are:

1. `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
2. `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`
3. `sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng`
4. `sudo apt-get install macchanger`

Hardware:

> 02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

I've been googling, and I found out that this is a hardware problem (Broadcom).
Is there anything I can do with it?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version? Which wifi card?

Comment: Ubuntu version is on the tag. Wifi card, based on my `lspci`: 02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

Answer (score 2):

To change your mac address you can try this:

1. `sudo service network-manager stop`
2. `sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` - Here you have to add a mac address you want. If you are connecting to the Internet over a wireless connection, then replace "eth0" with "wlan0" (wlan1, wlan2, etc.)
3. `sudo service network-manager restart`
4. `ifconfig` - check is mac changed

You can read more [here](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-change-mac-address-on-ubuntu.html).

If this is a hardware problem, I'm not sure if it will work, but try.